# Disassembler for intel 8080 v2

Tags: c++, file-system, assembly, c++17

As many suggestions were given for the code I posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200957/disassembler-for-intel-8080/200992#200992), I decided to show you the new version for review.

- I Removed the `OpenCatalog` class, `Disassembler` now has the responsibility for handling the catalog of `OpCode` that is now stored in an `std::map`.
- `OpCode` is now a `struct` and `AssemblyLine` handles the generation of the assembler code.
- `FileReaderHelper` is now `file_parse_helpers`, a namespace containing helper functions.
- I used `string_view` everywhere I though I could.
- I fixed all the things like initialization order, includes, spelling, consts, etc
- Reduced the amount of streams I was using.

**file_parse_helpers.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_PARSER_HELPER_H
#define FILE_PARSER_HELPER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace file_parse_helpers
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> splitString(std::string_view toSplit, std::string_view delimiter);
    int hexStringToInt(std::string_view toSplit);
    std::vector<unsigned char> loadBinaryFile(std::string filepath);
}

#endif // FILE_PARSER_HELPER_H
```

**file_parse_helpers.cpp**

```
#include "FileReaderHelper.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace file_parse_helpers
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> splitString(std::string_view toSplit, std::string_view delimiter)
    {
        std::vector<std::string_view> result;
        size_t lastPos = 0;

        while (lastPos < toSplit.size()) {
            const auto position = toSplit.find_first_of(delimiter, lastPos);

            if (lastPos != position) {
                result.emplace_back(toSplit.substr(lastPos, position - lastPos));
            }

            if (position == std::string_view::npos)
                break;

            lastPos = position + 1;
        }

        return result;
    }

    int hexStringToInt(std::string_view toSplit)
    {
        const auto pouet = std::strtol(toSplit.data(), 0, 16);
        return pouet;
    }

    std::vector<unsigned char> file_parse_helpers::loadBinaryFile(std::string filepath)
    {
        std::ifstream inputStream(filepath, std::ios::binary);
        std::vector<unsigned char> result(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{inputStream}, {});
        return result;
    }
}
```

**OpCode.h**

```
#ifndef OPCODE_H
#define OPCODE_H

#include <string>

struct OpCode {
    uint8_t code;
    int byteCount;
    std::string resultTemplate;
};

#endif // OPCODE_H
```

**AssemblyLine.h**

```
#ifndef ASSEMBLYLINE_H
#define ASSEMBLYLINE_H

#include <string>

#include "OpCode.h"

class AssemblyLine
{
public:
    AssemblyLine(const OpCode& opCode);
    AssemblyLine(const OpCode& opCode, const uint8_t param1);
    AssemblyLine(const OpCode& opCode, const uint8_t param1, const uint8_t param2);

    uint8_t getParam1() const;
    uint8_t getParam2() const;
    uint8_t getCode() const;
    uint8_t getByteCount() const;

    std::string generateAssembler(const std::string& templateString) const;

protected:
    const uint8_t byteCount;
    const uint8_t code;
    const uint8_t param1;
    const uint8_t param2;
};

#endif
```

**AsemblyLine.cpp**

```
#include "AssemblyLine.h"

#include <stdexcept>

AssemblyLine::AssemblyLine(const OpCode& opCode) :
    byteCount(opCode.byteCount),
    code(opCode.code),
    param1(0),
    param2(0)
{

}

AssemblyLine::AssemblyLine(const OpCode& opCode, const uint8_t param1) :
    byteCount(opCode.byteCount),
    code(opCode.code),
    param1(param1),
    param2(0)
{

}

AssemblyLine::AssemblyLine(const OpCode& opCode, const uint8_t param1, const uint8_t param2) :
    byteCount(opCode.byteCount),
    code(opCode.code),
    param1(param1),
    param2(param2)
{

}

uint8_t AssemblyLine::getParam1() const
{
    return param1;
}

uint8_t AssemblyLine::getParam2() const
{ 
    return param2;
}

uint8_t AssemblyLine::getCode() const
{
    return code;
}

uint8_t AssemblyLine::getByteCount() const
{
    return byteCount;
}

std::string AssemblyLine::generateAssembler(const std::string& templateString) const
{
    const int maxStringLength{ 32 };

    if (templateString.length() > maxStringLength)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("This template string is too long: " + templateString);
    }

    char temp[maxStringLength];
    switch (byteCount) {
    case 1:
        return templateString;
    case 2:
        std::snprintf(temp, maxStringLength, templateString.c_str(), param1);
        break;
    case 3:
        std::snprintf(temp, maxStringLength, templateString.c_str(), param1, param2);
        break;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**Disassembler.h**

```
#ifndef DISASSEMBLER_H
#define DISASSEMBLER_H


#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include "AssemblyLine.h"
#include "OpCode.h"

class Disassembler
{

public:
    Disassembler(const std::string& filename);
    std::vector<AssemblyLine> disassemble(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data);
    void printAssembly(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data);
    AssemblyLine disasembleOneCode(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data, size_t codeIndex);
    void loadCatalog(const std::string& filename);

private:
    std::map<uint8_t, OpCode> opCodes;
};

#endif
```

**Disassembler.cpp**

```
#include "Disassembler.h"
#include "File/FileReaderHelper.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

Disassembler::Disassembler(const std::string& filename)
{
    loadCatalog(filename);
}

AssemblyLine Disassembler::disasembleOneCode(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data, size_t codeIndex)
{
    uint8_t codeValue = data[codeIndex];
    const auto& opCode = opCodes[codeValue];
    const auto byteCount = opCode.byteCount;

    switch (byteCount) {
    default:
    case 1:
        return AssemblyLine(opCode);
        break;
    case 2:
        return AssemblyLine(opCode, data[codeIndex + 1]);
        break;
    case 3:
        return  AssemblyLine(opCode, data[codeIndex + 2], data[codeIndex + 1]);
        break;
    }
}

std::vector<AssemblyLine> Disassembler::disassemble(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data)
{
    size_t currentId = 0;
    std::vector<AssemblyLine> disasembledCode;
    for (; currentId < data.size() - 1;)
    {
        const auto asmLine = disasembleOneCode(data, currentId);
        currentId += asmLine.getByteCount();
        disasembledCode.emplace_back(asmLine);
    }
    return disasembledCode;
}

void Disassembler::loadCatalog(const std::string& filename)
{
    opCodes.clear();
    std::ifstream input(filename);
    for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line);)
    {
        const auto tokens = file_parse_helpers::splitString(line, "\t");

        if (tokens.size() < 3) {
            throw "Malformed catalog line: " + line;
        }

        uint8_t code = file_parse_helpers::hexStringToInt(std::string(tokens[0]));
        opCodes.emplace(code, OpCode{ code,
                                    std::stoi(std::string(tokens[2]), nullptr, 10),
                                    std::move(std::string(tokens[1])) });
    }
}

void Disassembler::printAssembly(const std::vector<unsigned char>& data)
{
    size_t currentId = 0;
    for (; currentId < data.size() - 1;)
    {
        const auto asmLine = disasembleOneCode(data, currentId);
        currentId += asmLine.getByteCount();
        std::cout << asmLine.generateAssembler(opCodes[asmLine.getCode()].resultTemplate) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Edit: After posting I realized that I made a mistake. I throw an exception about the size of the template string provided in the catalog, but I should do it when parsing the catalog, not when I use the string. Now, how do I replace `maxStringLength` so that I can use it when loading the catalog **and** as the size of the `temp` array in `generateAssembler`? Are C macros the only solution here?

Answer (score 3):

1. `loadBinaryFile` should either take a `std::string_view`, or, at least, a `std::string const&` as argument. You don't want to take ownership of the string here.
2. Your filenames do not match. `file_parse_helpers.cpp` begins with `#include "FileReaderHelper.h"`, but you don't show us the contents of that header. Presumably, you'd want to include `file_parse_helpers.h`.
3. You're missing the required includes for `size_t`, `uint8_t` and friends. Also, `::size_t`, `::uint8_t` etc. might not exist if you include the correct `<cheader>`, and should be replaced with `std::size_t` and `std::uint8_t`.
4. `hexStringToInt` is dangerous. `std::string_view` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, and if it isn't, you could be reading out of bounds and invoking undefined behavior.
5. Don't pass `0` to pointer arguments, pass `nullptr`. The latter is typesafe and indicates your intent clearly.
6. You can merge the three `AssemblyLine` constructors into one by adding default arguments: `AssemblyLine(OpCode const& opCode, uint8_t param1 = 0, uint8_t param2 = 0)`.
7. Why are the member variables of `AssemblyLine` protected? Doesn't look like you're planning on inheriting from it, so these should be private.
8. Beware of `const` member variables! While they might seem harmless on first sight, they're actually quite dangerous if you ever intend to put your objects into some sort of container. In fact, making a `std::vector<AssemblyLine>`, adding some elements, removing some elements, then adding some elements will invoke undefined behavior.
9. Don't use `printf` and friends; they're not type safe and don't always deal well with non-null-terminated strings. Either use the standard library facilities (i.e. iostreams), or make use of a modern formatting library, such as [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).
10. `disasembleOneCode` [sic] can exhibit undefined behavior since you don't do any bounds checking, and if `codeIndex + 2 >= data.size()`, then you're accessing somewhere you shouldn't.
11. `for (; currentId < data.size() - 1;)` should be expressed as `while (currentId < data.size() - 1)`.
12. Don't write `printX` functions. Instead, write either a function taking a `std::ostream` and writing to it, or overload `operator<<` for your class. The reason for this is that this makes printing a lot more flexible and enables you to print to many different sinks, without having to adjust the actual printing code.

---

To answer your question: *No*, you don't need a macro here at all. Just put `constexpr inline unsigned const maxStringLength = 32;` in a header and include it.

Comment: Sorry for the `#include "FileReaderHelper.h"`. The mistake is in the post actually, the name of the file is correct in the include. Should I edit the post? It looks like not working code like this.

Comment: @Stud No, I'd leave it like this. While it's technically not working code, most people are going to quickly realize that that's a simple copy-and-paste error.

Comment: Can you explain **8.** please? I do not understand why it leads to undefined behavior. About **10.**, do you mean that the check in `disassemble` is not enough and that I should check in `disasembleOneCode` too?

Comment: @Stud The issue behind point 8 is rather obscure and has to do with the quirks of the language. [This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0532r0.pdf) explains what I mean. About 10, `disasembleOneCode` is a public method, and can thus be called with any arguments whatsoever, which can lead to ub. Either prevent that by making it private, or make sure that it reacts to invalid arguments correctly, yes.

Comment: I think I've never heard of this issue before, thank you for the link and for the great answers.

Answer (score 3):

This version is improved, but there are still more things you can do to make it still better.

### Remove paths from local includes

It's generally better not to put the path explicitly in a local `#include` like this:

```
#include "File/FileReaderHelper.h"
```

Better is to omit that like this:

```
#include "FileReaderHelper.h"
```

and then point the compiler to the appropriate path.  This makes your source code cleaner, more portable and easier to maintain.

### Don't include redundant qualifications

In the same way that one shouldn't include the class name within class member function declarations, this line:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> file_parse_helpers::loadBinaryFile(std::string filepath)
```

because it already appears within the namespace declaration, should not have the namespace qualification and should instead be written like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> loadBinaryFile(std::string filepath)
```

### Let the user specify an output stream

The `printAssembly` function of the current `Disassembler` class is useful, but somewhat limited for two reasons.  The first reason is that it is hardcoded to only print to `std::cout`.  It would be more flexible to have a `std::ostream&` paramater an argument.  The second reason is mentioned in the next suggestion.

### Rethink the interface

The `Disassembler::printAssembly` function requires a `std::vector<unsigned char>&` argument.  I'd suggest that instead of specifically having such a structure, it might be useful to be rewrite it as a templated function to have it use any pair of iterators so that one could pass, say, `code.begin(), code.end()`.  The same change would be beneficial to `DisasembleOneCode` (which still has a spelling error, by the way).  Also, I'd suggest storing an `Opcode &` rather than just the opcode byte and bytecount within `AssemblyLine`.  This would make it much more useful because it would contain everything it needs to generate its own assembly output.  Also, instead of three separate constructors, just provide one with default parameters:

```
AssemblyLine(const OpCode& opCode, const uint8_t param1=0, const uint8_t param2=0);
```

Finally, I'd suggest that `generateAssembler()` might delegate to a member function of `Opcode` rather than needing to extract the `templateString` from the latter.

### Avoid storing data

The current code reads the entire binary file into memory, but if all we're doing is disassembling, that's not really needed.  Instead, one could make a single forward pass through the code and disassemble it on the fly.  Here's what my implementation looks like:

```
#include "Disassembler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: d8080 opcodefile binfile\n";
        return 1;
    };
    Disassembler d{argv[1]};
    std::ifstream bin{argv[2]};
    using iter = std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>;
    auto end{iter{}};
    for (auto curr{iter{bin}}; bin; ) {
        std::cout << d.disassembleOne(curr, end) << '\n';
    }
}
```

The `disassembleOne` function looks like this:

```
std::string Disassembler::disassembleOne(iter& begin, iter& end) const {
    if (begin == end)
        return "";
    auto op{opCodes.at(*begin++)};
    unsigned char param[2]{0,0};
    int i{0};
    switch (op.byteCount) {
        case 3:
            if (begin != end) 
                param[i++] = *begin++;
            // deliberately fall through
        case 2:
            if (begin != end) 
                param[i++] = *begin++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return op.asmString(param[0], param[1]);
}
```

Here's the slightly revised `OpCode.cpp`:

```
#include "OpCode.h"
#include <stdexcept>

std::string OpCode::asmString(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2) const {
    static constexpr int maxStringLength{ 32 };

    if (resultTemplate.length() > maxStringLength)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("This template string is too long: " + resultTemplate);
    }

    char temp[maxStringLength];
    switch (byteCount) {
    case 1:
        return resultTemplate;
    case 2:
        std::snprintf(temp, maxStringLength, resultTemplate.c_str(), param1);
        break;
    case 3:
        std::snprintf(temp, maxStringLength, resultTemplate.c_str(), param2, param1);
        break;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Note that in this revised version, only two classes, `Disassembler` and `OpCode` are used.

### Think of future expansion

Some things that might be useful for future features might be to keep track of the program counter, perhaps also optionally printing it and the disassembled byte values as part of the listing.  It's also probably useful to think about how this might be used for other small 8-bit processors, such as the Z80 and 6502.  I believe that all that would be required would be a different input opcode file.

### Checking string lengths

As to your question about how to check string lengths, the simplest would be to simply check when reading the opcode file.  No further checks are then necessary, since the opcode map does not change after construction.

Comment: Damn spelling... About your revised version, I decided to have two separate classes because I did not want to store a string per assembly line and I need to be able to return usable assembly information (I am writing a simulator for the 8080 as well). Thanks a lot for your answer again, great suggestions!

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you're also writing a simulator, it may make more sense to store things as you have.  I would still want each class to do more work and to encapsulate as much as possible.  Good luck!